# (CSS) How can I change style rules for of every second element in a multilevel list?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, pseudo-class

It is understood that I do not know the depth of the nesting of the list.

I want to see something like

- 1
- **2**
- 3

  - **3.1**
  - 3.2
  - **3.3**
- 4

  - **4.1**
  - 4.2

    - **4.2.1**
    - 4.2.2
- **5**

where bold elements are colored, for example, but I can build only this inaccurate variant:

```css
li {
  color: black;
}

li:nth-of-type(odd) {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3
    <ul>
      <li>3.1</li>
      <li>3.2</li>
      <li>3.3</li>
      <li>3.4</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5
    <ul>
      <li>5.1</li>
      <li>5.2
        <ul>
          <li>5.2.1</li>
          <li>5.2.2</li>
          <li>5.2.3</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>5.3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
</ul>
```

I also posted this code on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9mdkw7fq/).

Comment: May not be achievable without javascript.

Comment: I don't think you can accomplish this with pure css

Comment: This is unclear for me, because your code does what you (supposedly) want to. Note that in the title you only ask for the 2nd element of each nested `ul`, but on the example of `I want something like this` you are setting bold to each odd element, so you need to decide

Comment: @dippas the code isn't quite doing what the OP needs. Effectively what the OP wants is to get all descendant `li` in the outer `ul`, regardless of nesting and highlight alternate `li` from that grouping. Fairly trivial with jQuery/javascript, not so with css.

Comment: For a simple jQuery/CSS option see: http://jsfiddle.net/dobwkhz9/

Comment: Yes, I want to do this with pure css (an academic interest), this is impossible?

Comment: No, this is not possible with CSS.